# SetaPDF Compressor not there

Tags: php, pdf, setapdf

I wanted to compress a PDF with SetaPDF, but i dont find the Compressor File. Anyone know which file it is? Was it renamed because in the Internet i find references for a compressor class.

Ich searched on the Wiki, the sourcecode and so on.

Comment: We (the authors of SetaPDF) never had or have a "Compressor" thing.

Comment: @JanSlabon somebody mentioned it online, therefore i thougt there were one